# Download de arquivo - Excel - Firefox

Tags: microsoft-excel, firefox, download, atualização

tenho o link para download de um arquivo xls. Todo dia preciso BAIXAR esse arquivo(Só consigo acessar pelo firefox), SALVAR em um pasta para alimentar minha planilha.( a planilha tá "linkada" nesse arquivo.  Preciso de uma macro que faça: baixe esse arquivo(o link já tá pronto) automaticamente para uma pasta.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a seguinte função adaptada com seus dados:

```
Sub downloadFile()
    Dim myURL As String

    myURL = "http://portal.convenios.gov.br/images/docs/CGSIS/csv/siconv.zip" ' Coloque sua URL aqui!!!


    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    WinHttpReq.Send

    myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile ("C:\Users\user\Downloads\file.zip")
        oStream.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Código adaptado de:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd0ee306-7bb5-4ce4-8341-edd9475f84ad/excel-2007-use-vba-to-download-save-csv-from-url